# Access Object From JSON File in Powershell

Tags: json, list, powershell

I have a JSON file that I am reading in Powershell. The structure of the file is below.

```
[
    ["computer1", ["program1", versionX]],
    ["computer2", ["program2", versionY]],
    ["computer3", ["program3", "versionX"],
        ["program1", "versionZ"]
    ],
]
```

What I want in the program is use `$env:computername` and compare it with the computerX in the JSON file. If found a match, then iterate through and get the values of programName and ProgramVersion.

However, I don't know how to search through the objects and find ALL items under that.

This is what I have so far.

```
$rawData = Get-Content -Raw -Path "file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$computername=$env:computername
$data = $rawData -match $computername
```

This gives me objects under it. But how do I iterate through and get individual values?

But don't know what I do after that.

Comment: $rawData.psobject.properties will show three sections each has Name and Value the first (top) value reference is 0 and the last value reference in your example is 2 to get value $rawData.psobject.properties.Value[0]

Answer (score 0):

To start you need to be using a valid JSON file

```
    {
     "computer1":   {
        "program1": "versionX"
      },
     "computer2":   {
        "program2": "versionY"
      },
         "computer3":   {
        "program3": "versionX",
        "program1": "versionZ"
     }
   }
```

Then you can access the PSObject Properties

```
$rawData = Get-Content -Raw -Path "file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    $rawData.PsObject.Properties |
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
         ForEach-Object { IF ($_ -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
            Write-Host "Computer Name : " $_
            Write-Host "Value : " $rawData."$_"
        }
       }
```

**EDIT for Computer, Program, and Version as separate values**

> psobject.Properties.Name will give all the program names.
>
> psobject.Properties.Name[0] will give the first program name.
>
> psobject.Properties.value[0] will give the first program version value.

You need to increment the value to get second value, you can also use -1 as a shortcut for the last value.

```
$rawData = Get-Content -Raw -Path "file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

$rawData.PsObject.Properties |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
     ForEach-Object { IF ($_ -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
       $Computer = $_
       $Values = $rawData.$_
    }
   }


$Computer
$Values.psobject.Properties

$Values.psobject.Properties.Name

$Values.psobject.Properties.Name[0]
$Values.psobject.Properties.value[0]

$Values.psobject.Properties.Name[1]
$Values.psobject.Properties.value[1]
```

You could also use the program name

```
$Values.program1
$Values.program2
$Values.program3
```

Comment: what I want is Computer, Program, and Version as separate values. Sometime, computer has more than one program as well.

Comment: @Imsa see Edit for name and values